# Represent $15/(x^2-3x-54)$ as a power series by completing the square

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

You can find the problem attached to the figure below. It requires completing the square and finding the natural center of convergence and the open interval of convergence. Everything is doable until the last point which I'm not able to figure out. So, I completed the square as follows $$ f(x) = \frac{15}{((x-3/2)^2 - (3/2)^2 -54)} $$, fast forward factoring coefficients I achieve a power series of the form as follows $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty   -\frac{4^{(n+1)}}{15^{(n+1)}}(x-\frac{3}{2})^{2n}$$ with the center of convergence being $ a = \frac{3}{2} $. Nonetheless, it is incorrect. Is it the 2n power that is causing it to be incorrect implying that the power series should only be of the form $(x-a)^n$ and not $(x-a)^{kn}$ for some $k \in \mathbb R$? NOTE: The problem specifically asks to use the method of completing the square! Appreciate the help!

[image: The problem]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145184/discussion-on-question-by-tommy-represent-15-x2-3x-54-as-a-power-series-by); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're essentially trying to find the power series of
$$\frac{15}{\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{15}{2}\right)^2}$$
Which is just
$$15\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{\left(\frac{15}{2}\right)^{-n} + \left(-\frac{15}{2}\right)^{-n}}{2\left(\frac{15}{2}\right)^{2}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$$

Edit:
The expression we have is a scalar times an expression of the form
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-a^2} = \frac{1}{2 a (z-a)}-\frac{1}{2 a (a+z)} =- \frac{(-a)(z-a)^{-1}+a(z+a)^{-1}}{2a^2}$$
where we're expanding about $z=0$.
Let's use Taylor's theorem.

$$f(0) = -\frac{(-a)^{0} + a^{0}}{2a^2}$$
Consider the $n$-th derivative
$$f^n(z) = -n!\frac{(-1)^n(-a)(z-a)^{-n-1}+(-1)^na(z+a)^{-n-1}}{2a^2}$$
and so
$$\frac{f^n(0)}{n!} = -\frac{(-1)^{n}(-a)^{-n} + (-1)^n{a^{-n}}}{2a^2} = -\frac{a^{-n} + {(-a)^{-n}}}{2a^2}$$
Can you figure out the rest?

Edit 2:
First, let's simplify things a bit
$$15\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{\left(\frac{15}{2}\right)^{-n} + \left(-\frac{15}{2}\right)^{-n}}{2\left(\frac{15}{2}\right)^{2}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n 
= 
\frac{2}{15}\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\left(\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)^{n} + \left(-\frac{2}{15}\right)^{n}\right)\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$$

$$=\frac{2}{15}\sum_{n=0}^\infty -15^{-n}\left(2^n+(-2)^n\right)\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$$

Now let's $C$ be
$$C = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$$
so that the radius of convergence is $r = \frac{1}{C}$
$$C = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{2 \left(2^n + (-2)^n\right)}{15^{n+1}}\right|}$$
Obviously this is $0$ when $n$ is odd so we'll consider when $n$ is even
$$C = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{2^{n+2}}{15^{n+1}}\right|} = \frac{2}{15}$$
so the radius of convergence is
$$r = \frac{1}{C} = \frac{15}{2}$$
which means the series converges when
$$\left|x - \frac{3}{2}\right| < \frac{15}{2}$$
which means the interval of convergence is
$$-6 < x < 9$$
Edit 3: Let me explain how I got the simplified form:
After the simplification in edit 2, our solution was:
$$\frac{2}{15}\sum_{n=0}^\infty -15^{-n}\left(2^n+(-2)^n\right)\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$$
This can be rewritten as follows:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{2\left(2^n+(-2)^n\right)}{15^{n+1}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$$
Now notice that whenever $n$ is odd, our coefficients become $0$, so instead of iterating over all nonnegative integers we'll just iterate over the even ones via the substitution $n\mapsto 2n$ which gives us:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{2\left(2^{2n}+(-2)^{2n}\right)}{15^{2n+1}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}$$
Now since the $(-2)$ is being raised to an even power, we can ignore the negative sign. We get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{2\left(2^{2n}+(2)^{2n}\right)}{15^{2n+1}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n} = -\frac{2(2)(2^{2n})}{15^{2n+1}} \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}\\
= 
-\frac{2^{2n+2}}{15^{2n+1}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n} \\
= 
-\frac{4^{n+1}}{15^{2n+1}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}$$
Which is the simplified form. My $2n+3$ was a typo. The above is the correct form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although, could you elaborate a little more in detail on how you achieved this form? And what would be its open interval of convergence? Also, is there a reason for not putting the 15 inside and canceling a power of the denominator?

Comment: Interesting, haven't learned this one yet, thank you. In addition, I got the open interval of convergence by splitting it into two power series and then approaching them as geometrical series and got the result to be 9/8 < x < 21/8 which was incorrect. What way would you suggest on finding the interval of convergence?

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation, it really helps. So when I write the series inside the required field it looks as follows: $$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty  -15\frac{(\frac{15}{2})^{-n} + (\frac{-15}{2})^{-n}}{2 (\frac{15}{2})^2}(x-\frac{3}{2})^n$$ with center of convergence being $ a = \frac{3}{2}$ and open interval of convergence (-6,9).

Comment: The interval and the center are accepted as correct but the series is incorrect for some reason that I just can't see, even though I tried canceling and factoring and whatever but it doesn't work (note that every expression must be inside the sigma sum hence the 15 inside). Is it possible that the site evaluation is wrong? Additionally, I added a picture of the whole problem just in case I'm understanding it wrong. Can you check it for the last time? What do you think?

Comment: The issue is probably just that it accepts certain (simple) forms of the answer as opposed to more complicated ones since it doesn't have an internal simplification mechanism. It'll probably accept 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{n+1} - 2^{n+1}}{15^{n+1}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$$
which is just the series manipulated a little bit. Try it and let me know if it works. Also, if you appreciate my effort, please accept my answer.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you for your effort, it didn't accept it but I will guess that the system has something not evaluating it correctly or there is some crazy specific form it's requiring.

Comment: I would highly appreciate it if you could suggest it to someone who might have an idea for another form to define it, till then thank you again.

Comment: How about this form?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{4^{n+1}}{15^{2n+3}}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}$$

Comment: It was correct except 15 should be to the power of (2n+1). Maybe you can add it to your final answer. Thank you very much, again.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)
=\dfrac{15}{x^2-3x-54}
$

The roots of
$x^2-3x-54
$
are
$a=9, b=-6
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
&\text{For small }x\\
f(x)
&=\dfrac{15}{x^2-3x-54}\\
&=\dfrac{15}{(x-9)(x+6)}\\
&=\dfrac1{x - 9} - \dfrac1{x + 6}\\
&=\dfrac{-1/9}{1-x/9} - \dfrac{1/6}{1+x/6}\\
&=\dfrac{-1}{9}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{9^n}-\dfrac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{6^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{-1}{9}\dfrac{x^n}{9^n}-\dfrac{1}{6} \dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{6^n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\left(\dfrac{-1}{9^{n+1}}-\dfrac{(-1)^n}{6^{n+1}}\right)\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\left(\dfrac{3^{n+1}+(-1)^n2^{n+1}}{18^{n+1}}\right)\\
&\text{You can also write for large }x\\
f(x)
&=\dfrac{15}{x^2-3x-54}\\
&=\dfrac{15}{(x-9)(x+6)}\\
&=\dfrac1{x - 9} - \dfrac1{x + 6}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\left(\dfrac1{1 - 9/x} - \dfrac1{1 + 6/x}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{9^n}{x^n}-\dfrac{(-1)^n6^n}{x^n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{x^{n+1}}\left(9^n-(-1)^n6^n\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{3^n}{x^{n+1}}(3^n-(-1)^n2^n)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you for the answer although I specified in the description that the problem MUST use the completion of squares and find the representation around a center not equal to 0, rather than partial fractions (it's how the problem site requires it).